# Where can I get Google developer key

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-apps, google-data-api

I am working on Google API like chat, contacts and so on...
I am stuck on `developer_key` as mentioned in gdata doc.

You can get this at https://code.google.com/apis/console:

```
'developer_key' => ''
```

I have already:

```
// OAuth2 Settings, you can get these keys at https://code.google.com/apis/console
'oauth2_client_id' => '',
'oauth2_client_secret' => '',
'oauth2_redirect_uri' => ''
```

Where can I find developer key?

I found some thing like this

```
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html
```

But I understand this to be only for youtube.

Comment: You may accept the working answer. :)

Comment: @sjas I could not find developer key :( .

Comment: @sjas the OP is looking for something else.

Comment: Hey Guys, Its been 1 yr back ticket. so please excuse me I left that project. By they no answer so far is acceptable as they are not right.

Comment: Read this -- [https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2)

Comment: The Google systems are constantly in flux, so many of the answers refer to things that are obsolete.  Scroll down to *Recent Update July 2017* by @santoshthota. That worked for me today (Jan 27, 2121)

Answer (score 36):

It's the API key as listed under 'API Access', the 'Simple API Access' box.

Comment: is there man, under Simple API Access, see API key = developer key

Comment: Oh man I was asking for developer key :( not api key,secret key,client_id... I already found these keys ,But I was not able to find developer key. Once I found developer key that is in youtube developer console only!!

Comment: This is old, but for other people looking for the answer.  You need to enable the G+ service for the API key to show up.

Comment: Is API key = developer key ?

Comment: oh no its confusing so where is developer key, and i dont see Simple API either

Answer (score 29):

First activate Google+ API, then you will get "Simple API access" box, from there you can get 
developer key as API key
https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus 
or read this: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks for that man! Have been looking about 10 Minutes for that mysterious box...

Comment: Thank you, Chinthaka! Google+ is the key. This should be the best answer.

Answer (score 19):

### Update Nov 2015:

Sometime in late 2015, the Google Developers Console interface was overhauled again.  For the new interface:

1. Select your project from the toolbar.
   [image: screenshot]
2. Open the "Gallery" using hamburger menu icon on the left side of the toolbar and select 'API Manager'.
3. Click 'Credentials' in the left-hand navigation.

*Alternatively, you can click 'Switch to old console' under the the three-dot menu (right side of the toolbar), then follow the instructions below.*

### For the NEW (edit: OLD) Google Developers Console:

You get your 'Developer key' (a.k.a. API key) on the same screen where you get your client ID/secret.  (This is the 'Credentials' screen, which can be found under 'APIs & auth' in the left nav.)

Below your client ID keys, there is a section titled 'Public API access'. If there are no keys in this this section, click 'Create new Key'.  Your developer key is the 'API key' specified here.

Comment: The section under client id is email address. Is this my developer key? I doubt it.

Comment: @Euphorbium Email address is row below client Id and inside OAuth section. And section below OAuth is 'Public API access'.

Answer (score 17):

#### Update no 3:

You can get a **Developer_Key** from here [Get your Google Developer Key](https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html#settings)

[Check this tutorial](http://www.wmaker.net/help-appsv2-us/YouTube_a31.html)

{*select as answered, if it answered.*}

#### Update no 2:

## "API key" is the DEVELOPER_KEY

if you check this [code reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python_appengine),
it states

> Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the "API key" value from the "Access" tab of the Google APIs Console http://code.google.com/apis/console#access`

[Wiki on step by step to get API Key & secret](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/GettingAnOAuthConsoleKey)

#### Update:

#### Developer API Key! probably this is what you might be looking for

http://code.garyjones.co.uk/google-developer-api-key

OR

If say, for instance, you have a web app which would require a API key then check this:

1. Go to [Google API Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) Select you project OR Create your project.
2. Select APIs & Auths
   [image]
3. API Project from the Dropdown on the left navigation panel
4. API Access
5. Click on Create another Client ID
6. Select Service application [refer it here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?csw=1#scenarios)

The Service application that you have created can be used by your Web apps such as PHP, Python, ..., etc.
[image]

Comment: Question is about developer_key , and as per my understand page help to find Client secret and api key... Thanks for update! but I cant find developer key!

Comment: {select as answered, if it answered.}

Comment: There is no answered!

Comment: then the question is wrong, you are definitely looking for something else.

Comment: If you could see this question viewed 28609 times , so question is ok from my understanding. adn what you posted is not provide developer key. that only give you api key. and I think this is not true "API key" is the DEVELOPER_KEY.

Comment: the VIEWS have nothing to do with anything... & I think You didn't check the very **first line of my answer** (I have answered on getting a **API_KEY** as well as **DEVELOPER_KEY**) If that's not a **DEVELOPER KEY** that you are looking for,then make a GOOGLE for yourself

Comment: If you were looking for the same then I've answered you, & You should mark it as Answered.

Comment: Sorry I'm not looking for this, Please excuse me!

Comment: hmmm.. cool man. [Then try this](http://goo.gl/y6P4K0) & Mark **ANY ONE as ANSWERED** the choice is yours.

Comment: I was searching for the developer key. You answered it.

Answer (score 11):

**2017 Update**

1. Open Google API - https://console.developers.google.com
2. Go to Credentials.
3. Click on the 'Create Credentials' button. At time of writing it's currently a blue coloured dropdown.
4. Select API Key.

[image]

You should get a dialog from where you can copy this API key to use in your project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

In the old console layout :

- Select your project
- Select menu item "API access"
- Go to the section below "Create another client ID", called "Simple API Access"
- Choose one of the following options, depending on what kind of app you're creating (server side languages should use the first option - JS should use the second) :

  - Key for server apps (with IP locking)
  - Key for browser apps (with referers)

In the new cloud console layout :

- Select your project
- Choose menu item "APIs & auth"
- Choose menu item "Registered app"
- Register an app of type "web application"
- Choose one of the following options, depending on what kind of app you're creating (server side languages should use the first option - JS should use the second) :

  - Key for server apps (with IP locking)
  - Key for browser apps (with referers)

In case of both procedures, you find your client ID and client secret at the same page. If you're using a different client ID and client secret, replace it with the ones you find here.

During my first experiments today, I've succesfully used the "Key for server apps" as a developer key for connecting with the "contacts", "userinfo" and "analytics" API. I did this using the PHP client.

Wading through the Google API docs certainly is a pain in the @$$... I hope this info will be useful to anyone.

Comment: This is the correct answer!!! This worked for me for new console and OAuth2 api instead of these nonsenses above.

Comment: When we register an app by choosing "iOS", secret key is not generated. Do you know why ?

Comment: You should provide links so people know what you're talking about. Saying "cloud console" could mean a lot of different things, since Google's changes their site layout every 5 seconds. Case in point `https://console.cloud.google.com/` no longer has anything called "APIs & auth".

Comment: @Cerin : As Stephen M. Harris  pointed out in his answer, it looks like Google changed their GUI at least once more since I posted my answer 4 years ago...

Answer (score 6):

Please use [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
Create a new project
For the created project goto API access
There you will find your Client ID and Secret.
And the API key in the last is your developer key.

Comment: there are no API key in the last

Comment: There's no longer any page there called "API access".

Answer (score 5):

**Recent Update July 2017:**

1. Go to [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. Click on Left most top panel and click credentials.
   [image]
3. In the API keys table, you will find the API key in the key column.

Answer (score 2):

API Key is your developer key.
Hit https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key= in your browser by enabling web fonts api and you will see result.

Refer this blog http://code.garyjones.co.uk/google-developer-api-key/ for more information

Answer (score 0):

I explored the google docs and found that developer key and api is same thing.

Answer (score 0):

in https://code.google.com/apis/console/ , in SERVICES, turn on YOUTUBE API, then click API ACCESS in the left menu.

Answer (score 0):

"Public API access" the key generated there is the key you got to paste into your public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY as part of this writing 26.12.2013
It is not the clientID but you got take the steps mentioned above to obtain one and generate the public api access key.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Scroll down to where it says 'Visit the Google API Console to generate your developer key, OAuth2 client id, OAuth2 client secret, and register your OAuth2 redirect uri. Copy their values since your will need to input them in your application.'

Click on the 'Google API Console' link.

When it pops up and says 'Welcome to the new Google Developers Console! Prefer the old console? Go back |  Dismiss' Click on 'GO BACK'

Answer (score 0):

> If you are only calling APIs that do not require user data, such as
> the Google Custom Search API, then API keys might be simpler to use
> than OAuth 2.0 access tokens. However, if your application already
> uses an OAuth 2.0 access token, then there is no need to generate an
> API key as well. Google ignores passed API keys if a passed OAuth 2.0
> access token is already associated with the corresponding project.
>
> Note: You must use either an OAuth 2.0 access token or an API key for
> all requests to Google APIs represented in the Google Developers
> Console. Not all APIs require authorized calls. To learn whether
> authorization is required for a specific call, see your API
> documentation.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#credentials-access-security-and-identity

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

Developer Key = Api Key (any of yours)

find it in Google Console -> Google API -> Credentials

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to generate a Youtube API key [there](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/).

The recommended way to authorize your API call is to use OAuth 2.0 (without API key), as pointed by the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html#Auth) an API key is only necessary when using OAuth 1.0 credentials.

The API key for your application can be found in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console#access) in API Access > Simple API.

Comment: Yes! I am using the same .But I have doubt is that developer  key works for all google app?
By the way thank you for ur help..

Comment: Thanks @proppy: But I found here [doc_OAuth2WebServe](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#overview).
That is saying you need client_id and client_secret so on.. Is that I am on wrong place?

Comment: You should be able to use the OAuth 2.0 client_id, and client_secret genereated from the Google API console: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: No man what you have answered "API call is to use OAuth 2.0 (**without API key**), as pointed by the documentation an API key is only necessary when using OAuth 1.0 credentials." And as per my understanding you have to need client_id,secret_key... am I right ? Please help me!

Comment: You should be able to used either OAuth 2.0, or OAuth 1.0, with the same set of credential. Most of Google APIs support both authentification schemes.