# Google API Key Access and Android App

Tags: android, google-api, api-key

It's my first time that i use Google API. I use it with my Android App by using the beta google java api client. To test my app in the emulator, i took an API Key access from my google account and all work well. But now, what is the procedure about this API Key access if i want share my app in Google Play ? Do I leave my same Key access in the code or in the app, do i must ask final user to register with his own key acces with his google account ? Thank you for answer.

Comment: when u want to upload an app in the googleplay u need to get an all together new key that is private only to the app in the play.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi I use google api for google calendar

Comment: @ErrorHandler how can i do that ? Can you give me some steps to follow ?

Comment: For google calendar you dont need to change the key

Comment: @HardikTrivedi So, in other word for google api calendar, can we say that this key is independant of google accounts : users with their google accounts registered in their devices can use the app with the api key access that i generated with my google account without problems and security risk ?

Comment: Any key you generate independent to your keystore file, you can use same api key for any device

Answer (score 0):

This is simple steps that u need to follow instead of registering it in the site just register the key in Google play .[Here](http://www.higheredblogcon.com/library/deweese/presentation.html) is the link example to follow up also follow up with this SO chat u might get some idea [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832087/where-i-can-get-google-developer-key)

Answer (score 0):

You should go this path in terminal (cd *Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/*) Mac os, after that you can run command below

Create **Debug** key

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Create **Release** Key

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/macbook16/Documents/AndroidProjects/natural-therapy-android/app/keystore.jks  -alias myaliassample
```

Note : */Users/macbook16/Documents/AndroidProjects/natural-therapy-android/app/keystore.jks* this path is my project .jks file path, therefore you should replace your project jks file path, And ***myaliassample*** is exampl alias, you should replace the command like of your alias