# python code for retrieving count of followers and views of google plus profile

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

i am new to python and we are working on one project, which needs to collect information from google+ account through api.Tried the below code, but getting errors.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
service = build('plus', 'v1', developerKey='Client Secret')
people_service = service.people()
people_document = people_service.get(userId='me').execute()
print 'Display name: %s' % people_document.get('displayName')
```

error i am getting is : googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?alt=json&key=xxxx returned "Bad Request">.
Can any one suggest me what should be the developerkey in service object?

Comment: You need to get the key from google.  Check the api docs

Comment: i have created client_id and client_secret, is that developer key is same as client_secret?

Comment: Usually the way these things work is that you fill out a form for the api key, and they give you a long key.  You can't make one up.

Comment: Can you provide me the proper document links. Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832087/where-can-i-get-google-developer-key