# Unverified developer warning in personal app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Some days ago I wrote an app script with some support features to help me to take notes of my time in a google doc. It's my first one, I just wanted to test it and see if it could replace Microsoft Word Macros. The script is bound to the doc but I duplicate the file for each task I want to track time for. I don't intend to publish anything of the sort with google. It's just for my own use.
Now I have a bunch (like a lot) of 'unverified developer' warnings in google security page. Is there any easy way to tell google to f... off? I'm kind of offended... `unverified`... as I wasn't enduring this business the last almost 20 years. 8oD

Comment: I've seen I could register as a dev with google, but for doing that it asks for a project to publish, which I don't have.

Comment: I think you need to get a developer key, try to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832087/where-can-i-get-google-developer-key) if you need some assistance on process to get one.